does this npn gate driver circuit work?

this is a mosfet driver for a full bridge inverter. Does the circuit prevent the mosfets from turning on and short circuiting the inverter when the gate driver is powered?


Your circuit is something of a power hog.

Information is missing in the circuit. If the collector voltage is higher than $V_gs# of the MOSFET,  it would turn on. Where is the biasing circuit of the MOSFET?

a totem pole circuit will waste less energy.

Assuming the signal driving the 4k7 resistor is from an MCU, then if that signal is low, the 1st transistor is off. Therefore the 1k drives into the base of the 2nd, and it turns on against the 50 Ω. This has a forced beta of 20 which is likely sufficient. The on-transistor will have a very low VCE and keep the MOSFET off.
If the input signal does become high, the 1st transistor will turn on, shunting the 1k current to GND, and the 2nd device will turn off, allowing the MOSFET to turn on.
The 50 Ω will consume a significant current -- 12V/50 = 240 mA, and so 3 W. Using a higher resistance will also work, but the MOSFET switching speed may be slower.
